# Primefaces scrollable datatable width defined in percentage does not work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, primefaces, datatable, width

I am having problems with the primefaces (ver. 6.0) scrollable datatable width

**Problem :**

- If defined in percentage - regardless where I define it: in `style` or in `scrollWidth`. It works fine in IE (ver. 11), but in Firefox (ver. 52)/Edge (ver. 40) the table becomes as wide as all its colums.
- Since there are many columns, most of the table is invisible due to
  the physical width of the monitor.
- The scrollbar is there, but you
  can move it only just a bit, so I cannot scroll to see most of my
  columns.
- Everything works fine, if the datatable width is defined in
  px.

Is this a known problem? Does anyone know how to fix/work around
   it?

Comment: Known problems (known to the PrimeFaces team) are in their GitHub issue list. But you should start by trying a more recent versions.... FireFox 63.0.3 is the most recent and for PrimeFaces you should first try (just for this issue) a newer PrimeFaces version. 6.1 and 6.2 have been released and 6.3 is close to being release so the snapshot (build yourself) could be tried too) And did you try Chrome too?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Chrome (ver. 70) has the same problem as Firefox and Edge.

Comment: So most likely IE11 is wrong ;-)